# How to change res ID (R.raw.item_name) based on variable change in android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

extreme newbie here!

I have ten soundclips in the /res/raw directory.  I am using a single MediaPlayer instance (mp2) to play the clips.  I am currently using if statements to select the desired clip to play but I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this.  I want to change which of the ten clips is being played based on the value of the counter variable...so that if counter=1 clip "one" is played, if counter=2 clip "two" is played, etc.

Also a related question... if I have these ten clips in 4 different languages, how do I reference the correct clip based on user selection of the language within the app? (not system locale setting)

```
switch (me.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touched = true;
        counter = (counter + 1);
        // get soundfile from resources
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.hammer_blow);
        mp.start(); // Starts your sound
        if (counter == 1) {
            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.one);
            mp2.start();
        }// Starts your sound

        if (counter == 2) {
            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.two);
            mp2.start();
        }// Starts your sound

        if (counter == 3) {
            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.three);
            mp2.start();
        }// Starts your sound
```

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor the code to just include a switch on the counter;

```
int sound;
switch (counter)
{
case 1:
   sound = R.raw.one;
   break;
case 2:
   sound = R.raw.two;
   break;
etc.
}

mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
mp2.start();
```

I don't know about the language stuff. Maybe it's possible to set the app language to a user selected value? Then the raw resources would be figured out correctly.